# WARNING: "__aeabi_uldivmod" Undefined symbol in opendla.ko

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, intel-fpga

I am trying to build kernel module driver ([KMD](https://github.com/nvdla/sw/kmd)) for [NVDLA](https://github.com/nvdla/sw/tree/master/) NVIDIA's Deep Learning Accelerator and got the following error at the end.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0RTw.png)

After doing some research on google I found that it is due to 64bit operations (especially 64bit division) present in the kmd that is causing the errors. After further investigation I found that the kmd was written for 64bit architecture while I am trying to compile it for 32bit (ARM cortex A9) processor. some people online have suggested to use -lgcc, which will take care the issue.

Could anyone help me in editing the [makefile](https://github.com/nvdla/sw/blob/master/kmd/Makefile) to link the linker library libgcc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think it will work correctly after that?

Comment: @0andriy  To be honest I don't know. But when I searched for the error "needs unknown symbol __aeabi_uldivmod" I found some posts suggesting that it need to be link to libgcc.a which contains definition for __aeabi_uldivmod.  I wanted to try this and see if it works, but I am not familiar with makefiles, thats why I was hoping if someone could help link -lgcc with makefile.

The link for KMD and makfile is [here](https://github.com/nvdla/sw/tree/master/kmd) for your reference.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Generally it is better to include error messages, code, etc as text in the question (inside [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)), not as images or screen shots.  As text they are more accessible, and people can more easily copy and paste.

Comment: You need to use the functions from `#include <linux/math64.h>` to do 64-bit division. (The older `do_div()` macro from `#include <asm/div64.h>` is still used by some older code, but I wouldn't recommend it for new code because the macro does not behave like a normal function.)

Comment: Also, forget about using `-lgcc` because that is not supported in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux kernel code that uses 64-bit division should use the functions provided by `#include <linux/math64.h>`. Otherwise, when building for 32-bit architectures, GCC will attempt to use functions from `libgcc` which is not used by the kernel.

For example, the `div_u64` function divides a 64-bit unsigned dividend by a 32-bit unsigned divisor and returns a 64-bit unsigned quotient. The KMD code referenced by OP contains this function:

```
int64_t dla_get_time_us(void)
{
    return ktime_get_ns() / NSEC_PER_USEC;
}
```

After adding `#include <linux/math64.h>`, it can be rewritten to use the `div_u64` function as follows:

```
int64_t dla_get_time_us(void)
{
    return div_u64(ktime_get_ns(), NSEC_PER_USEC);
}
```

(Note that `ktime_get_ns()` returns a `u64` (an unsigned 64-bit integer) and `NSEC_PER_USEC` has the value 1000 so can be used as a 32-bit divisor.)

There may be other places in the code where 64-bit division is used, but that is the first one I spotted.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Abbott for the reply. It really helped me a lot. 

I used the div_u64 for division operation (/) and it worked and compiled fine without any error.
All though I used `#include <linux/math64.h> ` as ` #include <linux/math.h>` was giving error that no such file or directory exist.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I'll update the answer to fix that. (I got it correct in a comment on your question, but mistyped it in my answer!)

Comment: I am getting error when a try to insert the module `opendla`.

Comment: Error: 

`root@arria10:~# modprobe opendla
[   26.291567] opendla: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   26.298748] Probe NVDLA config nvidia,nv_small
[   26.305601] reset engine done
[   26.310481] [drm] Initialized nvdla 0.0.0 20171017 for ff200000.nvdla on minor 0
[   26.324761] vmap allocation for size 1073745920 failed: use vmalloc=<size> to increase size
[   26.333220] NVDLA ff200000.nvdla: failed to register drm device
[   26.339171] NVDLA: probe of ff200000.nvdla failed with error -12`

Driver is supposed to use a reserved memory of 1GB. as written in the driver code

Comment: Driver code:  
`dma = dma_declare_coherent_memory(drm->dev, 0x40000000, 0x40000000,
   0x40000000,  DMA_MEMORY_EXCLUSIVE);
 if ((dma  )) {
  err = -ENOMEM;
  goto unref;
 }` 
device-tree-node definition for reserved memory 
`reserved-memory {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        ranges;
        nvdla_mem: buffer@0x40000000 {
            no-map ;
            reg = <0x0 0x40000000 0x0 0x40000000>;
            
        };
    };`

Comment: Could you please also look into the above issue. I have also asked the device tree related issues [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68097965/memory-maped-node-in-a-device-tree-is-not-getting-shown-in-proc-iomem) separately.

Comment: The address space for `vmap` and `vmalloc` and `ioremap` needs to fit in the kernel's address space. Most 32-bit systems use a 3G/1G user/kernel split of the 4GiB address space (3GiB user space and 1GiB kernel space). So you are trying to map 1GiB of address space for your reserved memory into the kernel's total 1GiB address space which is impossible because parts of that address space are already in use by the kernel. You will need to reconfigure the kernel to use a 2G/2G split (or possibly a 1G/3G split) to stand any chance of it working.

Comment: I have reduced the size of reserved memory to 500M and change kernel configuration to 2G/2G. It inserted without error. 
But when I did `cat /proc/meminfo`. it is still showing zero as used vmalloc memory. How can I know that the memory from `0x40000000 to 0x600000000` a size of 500M is assigned to the NVDLA_IP, correctly.

Comment: Could please explain details about the fucntion dma_declare_coherent_memory and how I can know that It has is using the reserved memory region That I have defined in the device tree. 

Actually When I tried to run NVDLA application, I am getting error that ` Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ...`. I am suspecting it because that this error is because of memory allocation issue. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShahidUllah This is getting horribly off-topic. Please start another question.