# Memory-Maped Node in a Device Tree is not getting shown in /proc/iomem

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree, intel-fpga

I am trying to add a custom memory-mapped component in intel FPGA based soc system. I have connected the custom component(NVDLA) with light-weight axi bridge (HPS to FPGA bridge). Device Tree File.

```
/dts-v1/;
/ {
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    #size-cells = <0x1>;
    model = "Terasic HAN Pilot (Arria 10 SX) ";
    compatible = "altr,socfpga-arria10", "altr,socfpga";

    cpus {
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;
        enable-method = "altr,socfpga-a10-smp";

        cpu@0 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x0>;
            next-level-cache = <0x1>;
        };

        cpu@1 {
            compatible =  "arm,cortex-a9";
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x1>;
            next-level-cache = <0x1>;
        };
    };

    intc@ffffd000 {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-gic-20.1", "arm,cortex-a9-gic";
        #interrupt-cells = <0x3>;
        interrupt-controller;
        reg = <0xffffd000 0x1000 0xffffc100 0x100>;
        phandle = <0x2>;
    };
    reserved-memory {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        ranges;
        nvdla_mem: buffer@0x40000000 {
            no-map ;
            reg = <0x0 0x40000000 0x0 0x40000000>;
            
        };
    };
    soc {
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        device_type = "soc";
        interrupt-parent = <0x2>;
        ranges;

    
    arria10_hps_bridges: bridge@0xff200000 {
            compatible = "simple-bus";
            reg = <0xff200000 0x00200000>;
            clocks = <0x2c 0x2c>;
            clock-names = "h2f_lw_axi_clock", "f2sdram0_clock";
            #address-cells = <2>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            ranges = <0x00000001 0x00000000 0xff200000 0x00040000>;

            NVDLA_IP_0: nvdla@0x100000000 {
                compatible = "nvidia,nv_small";
                reg = <0x00000001 0x00000000 0x00040000>;
                interrupt-parent = <0x2>;
                interrupts = <0 19 4>;
                clocks = <0x2c 0x2c 0x2c>;
                clock-names = "clock", "dla_core_clock", "dla_csb_clock";
                memory-region = <&nvdla_mem>;
            }; //end unknown@0x100000000 (NVDLA_IP_0)
        }; //end bridge@0xff200000 (arria10_hps_bridges)
    
        amba {
            compatible = "simple-bus";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            ranges;

            pdma@ffda1000 {
                compatible = "arm,pl330-20.1", "arm,pl330", "arm,primecell";
                reg = <0xffda1000 0x1000>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x53 0x4 0x0 0x54 0x4 0x0 0x55 0x4 0x0 0x56 0x4 0x0 0x57 0x4 0x0 0x58 0x4 0x0 0x59 0x4 0x0 0x5a 0x4 0x0 0x5b 0x4>;
                #dma-cells = <0x1>;
                #dma-channels = <0x8>;
                #dma-requests = <0x20>;
                clocks = <0x3>;
                clock-names = "apb_pclk";
                microcode-cached;
                phandle = <0x1e>;
            };
        };

        clkmgr@ffd04000 {
            compatible = "altr,clk-mgr-20.1", "altr,clk-mgr";
            reg = <0xffd04000 0x1000>;

            clocks {
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x0>;

                clk_100 {
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    clock-frequency = <0x5f5e100>;
                    clock-output-names = "clk_100-clk";
                    phandle = <0x2c>;
                };

                clk_50 {
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    clock-frequency = <0x2faf080>;
                    clock-output-names = "clk_50-clk";
                };

                cb_intosc_hs_div2_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    phandle = <0xd>;
                };

                cb_intosc_ls_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    phandle = <0x6>;
                };

                f2s_free_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    clock-frequency = <0x2faf080>;
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    phandle = <0x7>;
                };

                osc1 {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    clock-frequency = <0x17d7840>;
                    phandle = <0x5>;
                };

                main_pll@40 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-pll-clock";
                    clocks = <0x5 0x6 0x7>;
                    reg = <0x40>;
                    phandle = <0x8>;

                    main_mpu_base_clk {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        div-reg = <0x140 0x0 0xb>;
                        phandle = <0xb>;
                    };

                    main_noc_base_clk {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        div-reg = <0x144 0x0 0xb>;
                        phandle = <0xe>;
                    };

                    main_emaca_clk@68 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x68>;
                        phandle = <0x2d>;
                    };

                    main_emacb_clk@6c {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x6c>;
                        phandle = <0x2e>;
                    };

                    main_emac_ptp_clk@70 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x70>;
                        phandle = <0x2f>;
                    };

                    main_gpio_db_clk@74 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x74>;
                        phandle = <0x30>;
                    };

                    main_sdmmc_clk@78 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x78>;
                        phandle = <0x12>;
                    };

                    main_s2f_usr0_clk@7c {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x7c>;
                        phandle = <0x31>;
                    };

                    main_s2f_usr1_clk@80 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x80>;
                        phandle = <0x10>;
                    };

                    main_hmc_pll_ref_clk@84 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x84>;
                        phandle = <0x32>;
                    };

                    main_periph_ref_clk@9c {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0x8>;
                        reg = <0x9c>;
                        phandle = <0x9>;
                    };
                };

                periph_pll@c0 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-pll-clock";
                    clocks = <0x5 0x6 0x7 0x9>;
                    reg = <0xc0>;
                    phandle = <0xa>;

                    peri_mpu_base_clk {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        div-reg = <0x140 0x10 0xb>;
                        phandle = <0xc>;
                    };

                    peri_noc_base_clk {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        div-reg = <0x144 0x10 0xb>;
                        phandle = <0xf>;
                    };

                    peri_emaca_clk@e8 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0xe8>;
                        phandle = <0x33>;
                    };

                    peri_emacb_clk@ec {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0xec>;
                        phandle = <0x34>;
                    };

                    peri_emac_ptp_clk@f0 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0xf0>;
                        phandle = <0x35>;
                    };

                    peri_gpio_db_clk@f4 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0xf4>;
                        phandle = <0x36>;
                    };

                    peri_sdmmc_clk@f8 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0xf8>;
                        phandle = <0x13>;
                    };

                    peri_s2f_usr0_clk@fc {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0xfc>;
                        phandle = <0x37>;
                    };

                    peri_s2f_usr1_clk@100 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0x100>;
                        phandle = <0x11>;
                    };

                    peri_hmc_pll_ref_clk@104 {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                        clocks = <0xa>;
                        reg = <0x104>;
                        phandle = <0x38>;
                    };
                };

                mpu_free_clk@60 {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                    clocks = <0xb 0xc 0x5 0xd 0x7>;
                    reg = <0x60>;
                    phandle = <0x15>;
                };

                noc_free_clk@64 {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                    clocks = <0xe 0xf 0x5 0xd 0x7>;
                    reg = <0x64>;
                    phandle = <0x14>;
                };

                s2f_user1_free_clk@104 {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                    clocks = <0x10 0x11 0x5 0xd 0x7>;
                    reg = <0x104>;
                    phandle = <0x39>;
                };

                sdmmc_free_clk@f8 {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                    clocks = <0x12 0x13 0x5 0xd 0x7>;
                    fixed-divider = <0x4>;
                    reg = <0xf8>;
                    phandle = <0x16>;
                };

                l4_sys_free_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-perip-clk";
                    clocks = <0x14>;
                    fixed-divider = <0x4>;
                    phandle = <0x29>;
                };

                l4_main_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x14>;
                    div-reg = <0xa8 0x0 0x2>;
                    clk-gate = <0x48 0x1>;
                    phandle = <0x3>;
                };

                l4_mp_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x14>;
                    div-reg = <0xa8 0x8 0x2>;
                    clk-gate = <0x48 0x2>;
                    phandle = <0x17>;
                };

                l4_sp_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x14>;
                    div-reg = <0xa8 0x10 0x2>;
                    clk-gate = <0x48 0x3>;
                    phandle = <0x1c>;
                };

                mpu_periph_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x15>;
                    fixed-divider = <0x4>;
                    clk-gate = <0x48 0x0>;
                    phandle = <0x28>;
                };

                sdmmc_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x16>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0x5>;
                    clk-phase = <0x0 0x87>;
                    phandle = <0x20>;
                };

                qspi_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x3>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0xb>;
                    phandle = <0x27>;
                };

                nand_x_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x17>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0xa>;
                    phandle = <0x18>;
                };

                nand_ecc_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x18>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0xa>;
                    phandle = <0x22>;
                };

                nand_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x18>;
                    fixed-divider = <0x4>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0xa>;
                    phandle = <0x21>;
                };

                spi_m_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x3>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0x9>;
                    phandle = <0x1d>;
                };

                usb_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x17>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0x8>;
                    phandle = <0x2a>;
                };

                s2f_usr1_clk {
                    #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                    compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-gate-clk";
                    clocks = <0x11>;
                    clk-gate = <0xc8 0x6>;
                    phandle = <0x3a>;
                };
            };
        };

        stmmac-axi-config {
            snps,wr_osr_lmt = <0xf>;
            snps,rd_osr_lmt = <0xf>;
            snps,blen = <0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10 0x0 0x0>;
            phandle = <0x1b>;
        };

        ethernet@ff800000 {
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-stmmac", "snps,dwmac-3.72a", "snps,dwmac";
            altr,sysmgr-syscon = <0x19 0x44 0x0>;
            reg = <0xff800000 0x2000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x5c 0x4>;
            interrupt-names = "macirq";
            mac-address = [d6 7d ae b3 0e bc];
            snps,multicast-filter-bins = <0x100>;
            snps,perfect-filter-entries = <0x80>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x1000>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x4000>;
            clocks = <0x17>;
            clock-names = "stmmaceth";
            resets = <0x1a 0x20>;
            reset-names = "stmmaceth";
            snps,axi-config = <0x1b>;
            status = "okay";
            phy-mode = "rgmii";
            phy-addr = <0xffffffff>;
            txd0-skew-ps = <0x0>;
            txd1-skew-ps = <0x0>;
            txd2-skew-ps = <0x0>;
            txd3-skew-ps = <0x0>;
            rxd0-skew-ps = <0x1a4>;
            rxd1-skew-ps = <0x1a4>;
            rxd2-skew-ps = <0x1a4>;
            rxd3-skew-ps = <0x1a4>;
            txen-skew-ps = <0x0>;
            txc-skew-ps = <0x744>;
            rxdv-skew-ps = <0x1a4>;
            rxc-skew-ps = <0x690>;
            max-frame-size = <0xed8>;
            phandle = <0x24>;
        };

        ethernet@ff802000 {
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-stmmac", "snps,dwmac-3.72a", "snps,dwmac";
            altr,sysmgr-syscon = <0x19 0x48 0x0>;
            reg = <0xff802000 0x2000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x5d 0x4>;
            interrupt-names = "macirq";
            mac-address = [00 00 00 00 00 00];
            snps,multicast-filter-bins = <0x100>;
            snps,perfect-filter-entries = <0x80>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x1000>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x4000>;
            clocks = <0x17>;
            clock-names = "stmmaceth";
            resets = <0x1a 0x21>;
            reset-names = "stmmaceth";
            snps,axi-config = <0x1b>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x3b>;
        };

        ethernet@ff804000 {
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-stmmac", "snps,dwmac-3.72a", "snps,dwmac";
            altr,sysmgr-syscon = <0x19 0x4c 0x0>;
            reg = <0xff804000 0x2000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x5e 0x4>;
            interrupt-names = "macirq";
            mac-address = [00 00 00 00 00 00];
            snps,multicast-filter-bins = <0x100>;
            snps,perfect-filter-entries = <0x80>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x1000>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x4000>;
            clocks = <0x17>;
            clock-names = "stmmaceth";
            snps,axi-config = <0x1b>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x3c>;
        };

        gpio@ffc02900 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio";
            reg = <0xffc02900 0x100>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x3d>;

            gpio-controller@0 {
                compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio-port";
                gpio-controller;
                #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
                snps,nr-gpios = <0x1d>;
                reg = <0x0>;
                interrupt-controller;
                #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x70 0x4>;
                phandle = <0x3e>;
            };
        };

        gpio@ffc02a00 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio";
            reg = <0xffc02a00 0x100>;
            status = "okay";
            phandle = <0x3f>;

            gpio-controller@0 {
                compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio-port";
                gpio-controller;
                #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
                snps,nr-gpios = <0x1d>;
                reg = <0x0>;
                interrupt-controller;
                #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x71 0x4>;
                phandle = <0x1f>;
            };
        };

        gpio@ffc02b00 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio";
            reg = <0xffc02b00 0x100>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x40>;

            gpio-controller@0 {
                compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio-port";
                gpio-controller;
                #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
                snps,nr-gpios = <0x1b>;
                reg = <0x0>;
                interrupt-controller;
                #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x72 0x4>;
                phandle = <0x41>;
            };
        };

        fpga-mgr@ffd03000 {
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-fpga-mgr";
            reg = <0xffd03000 0x100 0xffcfe400 0x20>;
            clocks = <0x17>;
            resets = <0x1a 0x83>;
            reset-names = "fpgamgr";
            phandle = <0x4>;
        };

        i2c@ffc02200 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
            reg = <0xffc02200 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x69 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "okay";
            phandle = <0x42>;

            ds1339@68 {
                compatible = "dallas,ds1339", "mxim,ds1339";
                reg = <0x68>;
                trickle-resistor-ohms = <0xfa>;
                trickle-diode-disable;
            };
        };

        i2c@ffc02300 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
            reg = <0xffc02300 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x6a 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "disabled";
            clock-frequency = <0x186a0>;
            i2c-sda-falling-time-ns = <0x1770>;
            i2c-scl-falling-time-ns = <0x1770>;
            phandle = <0x43>;
        };

        i2c@ffc02400 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
            reg = <0xffc02400 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x6b 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x45>;
        };

        i2c@ffc02500 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
            reg = <0xffc02500 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x6c 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x46>;
        };

        i2c@ffc02600 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "snps,designware-i2c";
            reg = <0xffc02600 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x6d 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x47>;
        };

        spi@ffda4000 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-ssi";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            reg = <0xffda4000 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x65 0x4>;
            num-cs = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1d>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x48>;
        };

        spi@ffda5000 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-ssi";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            reg = <0xffda5000 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x66 0x4>;
            num-cs = <0x4>;
            tx-dma-channel = <0x1e 0x10>;
            rx-dma-channel = <0x1e 0x11>;
            clocks = <0x1d>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x49>;
        };

        sdr@ffcfb100 {
            compatible = "altr,sdr-ctl", "syscon";
            reg = <0xffcfb100 0x80>;
            phandle = <0x23>;
        };

        l2-cache@fffff000 {
            compatible = "arm,pl310-cache";
            reg = <0xfffff000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x12 0x4>;
            cache-unified;
            cache-level = <0x2>;
            prefetch-data = <0x1>;
            prefetch-instr = <0x1>;
            arm,shared-override;
            phandle = <0x1>;
        };

        dwmmc0@ff808000 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-dw-mshc";
            reg = <0xff808000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x62 0x4>;
            fifo-depth = <0x400>;
            clocks = <0x17 0x20>;
            clock-names = "biu", "ciu";
            status = "okay";
            cap-sd-highspeed;
            cap-mmc-highspeed;
            broken-cd;
            bus-width = <0x4>;
            phandle = <0x26>;
        };

        nand@ffb90000 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-denali-nand";
            reg = <0xffb90000 0x72000 0xffb80000 0x10000>;
            reg-names = "nand_data", "denali_reg";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x63 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x21 0x18 0x22>;
            clock-names = "nand", "nand_x", "ecc";
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x4b>;
        };

        sram@ffe00000 {
            compatible = "mmio-sram";
            reg = <0xffe00000 0x40000>;
            phandle = <0x4c>;
        };

        eccmgr {
            compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-ecc-manager";
            altr,sysmgr-syscon = <0x19>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2 0x4 0x0 0x0 0x4>;
            interrupt-controller;
            #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
            ranges;
            phandle = <0x4d>;

            sdramedac {
                compatible = "altr,sdram-edac-a10";
                altr,sdr-syscon = <0x23>;
                interrupts = <0x11 0x4 0x31 0x4>;
            };

            l2-ecc@ffd06010 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-l2-ecc";
                reg = <0xffd06010 0x4>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x4 0x20 0x4>;
            };

            ocram-ecc@ff8c3000 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-a10-ocram-ecc";
                reg = <0xff8c3000 0x400>;
                interrupts = <0x1 0x4 0x21 0x4>;
            };

            emac0-rx-ecc@ff8c0800 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-eth-mac-ecc";
                reg = <0xff8c0800 0x400>;
                altr,ecc-parent = <0x24>;
                interrupts = <0x4 0x4 0x24 0x4>;
            };

            emac0-tx-ecc@ff8c0c00 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-eth-mac-ecc";
                reg = <0xff8c0c00 0x400>;
                altr,ecc-parent = <0x24>;
                interrupts = <0x5 0x4 0x25 0x4>;
            };

            dma-ecc@ff8c8000 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-dma-ecc";
                reg = <0xff8c8000 0x400>;
                altr,ecc-parent = <0x1e>;
                interrupts = <0xa 0x4 0x2a 0x4>;
            };

            usb0-ecc@ff8c8800 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-usb-ecc";
                reg = <0xff8c8800 0x400>;
                altr,ecc-parent = <0x25>;
                interrupts = <0x2 0x4 0x22 0x4>;
            };

            sdmmca-ecc@ff8c2c00 {
                compatible = "altr,socfpga-sdmmc-ecc";
                reg = <0xff8c2c00 0x400>;
                altr,ecc-parent = <0x26>;
                interrupts = <0xf 0x4 0x2f 0x4 0x10 0x4 0x30 0x4>;
            };
        };

        spi@ff809000 {
            compatible = "cdns,qspi-nor";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            reg = <0xff809000 0x100 0xffa00000 0x100000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x64 0x4>;
            cdns,fifo-depth = <0x80>;
            cdns,fifo-width = <0x4>;
            cdns,trigger-address = <0x0>;
            clocks = <0x27>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x4e>;
        };

        rstmgr@ffd05000 {
            #reset-cells = <0x1>;
            compatible = "altr,rst-mgr";
            reg = <0xffd05000 0x100>;
            altr,modrst-offset = <0x20>;
            phandle = <0x1a>;
        };

        snoop-control-unit@ffffc000 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-scu";
            reg = <0xffffc000 0x100>;
            phandle = <0x4f>;
        };

        sysmgr@ffd06000 {
            compatible = "altr,sys-mgr", "syscon";
            reg = <0xffd06000 0x300>;
            cpu1-start-addr = <0xffd06230>;
            phandle = <0x19>;
        };

        timer@ffffc600 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-twd-timer";
            reg = <0xffffc600 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x1 0xd 0xf01>;
            clocks = <0x28>;
        };

        timer0@ffc02700 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-timer";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x73 0x4>;
            reg = <0xffc02700 0x100>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            clock-names = "timer";
            resets = <0x1a 0x44>;
            reset-names = "timer";
            phandle = <0x50>;
        };

        timer1@ffc02800 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-timer";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x74 0x4>;
            reg = <0xffc02800 0x100>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            clock-names = "timer";
            resets = <0x1a 0x45>;
            reset-names = "timer";
            phandle = <0x51>;
        };

        timer2@ffd00000 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-timer";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x75 0x4>;
            reg = <0xffd00000 0x100>;
            clocks = <0x29>;
            clock-names = "timer";
            resets = <0x1a 0x42>;
            reset-names = "timer";
            phandle = <0x52>;
        };

        timer3@ffd00100 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-timer";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x76 0x4>;
            reg = <0xffd01000 0x100>;
            clocks = <0x29>;
            clock-names = "timer";
            resets = <0x1a 0x43>;
            reset-names = "timer";
            phandle = <0x53>;
        };

        serial0@ffc02000 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-uart";
            reg = <0xffc02000 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x6e 0x4>;
            reg-shift = <0x2>;
            reg-io-width = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x54>;
        };

        serial1@ffc02100 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-apb-uart";
            reg = <0xffc02100 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x6f 0x4>;
            reg-shift = <0x2>;
            reg-io-width = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1c>;
            status = "okay";
            phandle = <0x55>;
        };

        usbphy {
            #phy-cells = <0x0>;
            compatible = "usb-nop-xceiv";
            status = "okay";
            phandle = <0x2b>;
        };

        usb@ffb00000 {
            compatible = "snps,dwc2";
            reg = <0xffb00000 0xffff>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x5f 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x2a>;
            clock-names = "otg";
            resets = <0x1a 0x23>;
            reset-names = "dwc2";
            phys = <0x2b>;
            phy-names = "usb2-phy";
            status = "okay";
            disable-over-current;
            phandle = <0x25>;
        };

        usb@ffb40000 {
            compatible = "snps,dwc2";
            reg = <0xffb40000 0xffff>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x60 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x2a>;
            clock-names = "otg";
            resets = <0x1a 0x24>;
            reset-names = "dwc2";
            phys = <0x2b>;
            phy-names = "usb2-phy";
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x56>;
        };

        watchdog@ffd00200 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-wdt";
            reg = <0xffd00200 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x77 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x29>;
            status = "disabled";
            phandle = <0x57>;
        };

        watchdog@ffd00300 {
            compatible = "snps,dw-wdt";
            reg = <0xffd00300 0x100>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x78 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x29>;
            status = "okay";
            phandle = <0x58>;
        };
    };

    aliases {
        ethernet0 = "/soc/ethernet@ff800000";
        serial0 = "/soc/serial1@ffc02100";
    };

    chosen {
        bootargs = "earlyprintk";
        stdout-path = "serial0:115200n8";
        cff-file = "socfpga.periph.rbf";
        early-release-fpga-config;
    };

    memory@0 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x80000000>;
    };

    a10leds {
        compatible = "gpio-leds";

        led0 {
            label = "hps_led0";
            gpios = <0x41 0x1 0x1>;
            linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
            default-state = "on";
        };
    };

    gpio-keys {
        compatible = "gpio-keys";

        key0 {
            label = "hps_key0";
            linux,code = <0x67>;
            gpios = <0x41 0x4 0x1>;
        };
    };

    __symbols__ {
        intc = "/intc@ffffd000";
        pdma = "/soc/amba/pdma@ffda1000";
        cb_intosc_hs_div2_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/cb_intosc_hs_div2_clk";
        cb_intosc_ls_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/cb_intosc_ls_clk";
        f2s_free_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/f2s_free_clk";
        osc1 = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/osc1";
        main_pll = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40";
        main_mpu_base_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_mpu_base_clk";
        main_noc_base_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_noc_base_clk";
        main_emaca_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_emaca_clk@68";
        main_emacb_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_emacb_clk@6c";
        main_emac_ptp_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_emac_ptp_clk@70";
        main_gpio_db_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_gpio_db_clk@74";
        main_sdmmc_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_sdmmc_clk@78";
        main_s2f_usr0_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_s2f_usr0_clk@7c";
        main_s2f_usr1_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_s2f_usr1_clk@80";
        main_hmc_pll_ref_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_hmc_pll_ref_clk@84";
        main_periph_ref_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/main_pll@40/main_periph_ref_clk@9c";
        periph_pll = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0";
        peri_mpu_base_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_mpu_base_clk";
        peri_noc_base_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_noc_base_clk";
        peri_emaca_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_emaca_clk@e8";
        peri_emacb_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_emacb_clk@ec";
        peri_emac_ptp_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_emac_ptp_clk@f0";
        peri_gpio_db_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_gpio_db_clk@f4";
        peri_sdmmc_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_sdmmc_clk@f8";
        peri_s2f_usr0_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_s2f_usr0_clk@fc";
        peri_s2f_usr1_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_s2f_usr1_clk@100";
        peri_hmc_pll_ref_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/periph_pll@c0/peri_hmc_pll_ref_clk@104";
        mpu_free_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/mpu_free_clk@60";
        noc_free_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/noc_free_clk@64";
        s2f_user1_free_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/s2f_user1_free_clk@104";
        sdmmc_free_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/sdmmc_free_clk@f8";
        l4_sys_free_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/l4_sys_free_clk";
        l4_main_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/l4_main_clk";
        l4_mp_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/l4_mp_clk";
        l4_sp_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/l4_sp_clk";
        mpu_periph_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/mpu_periph_clk";
        sdmmc_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/sdmmc_clk";
        qspi_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/qspi_clk";
        nand_x_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/nand_x_clk";
        nand_ecc_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/nand_ecc_clk";
        nand_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/nand_clk";
        spi_m_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/spi_m_clk";
        usb_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/usb_clk";
        s2f_usr1_clk = "/soc/clkmgr@ffd04000/clocks/s2f_usr1_clk";
        socfpga_axi_setup = "/soc/stmmac-axi-config";
        gmac0 = "/soc/ethernet@ff800000";
        gmac1 = "/soc/ethernet@ff802000";
        gmac2 = "/soc/ethernet@ff804000";
        gpio0 = "/soc/gpio@ffc02900";
        porta = "/soc/gpio@ffc02900/gpio-controller@0";
        gpio1 = "/soc/gpio@ffc02a00";
        portb = "/soc/gpio@ffc02a00/gpio-controller@0";
        gpio2 = "/soc/gpio@ffc02b00";
        portc = "/soc/gpio@ffc02b00/gpio-controller@0";
        fpga_mgr = "/soc/fpga-mgr@ffd03000";
        i2c0 = "/soc/i2c@ffc02200";
        i2c1 = "/soc/i2c@ffc02300";
        lcd = "/soc/i2c@ffc02300/lcd@28";
        i2c2 = "/soc/i2c@ffc02400";
        i2c3 = "/soc/i2c@ffc02500";
        i2c4 = "/soc/i2c@ffc02600";
        spi0 = "/soc/spi@ffda4000";
        spi1 = "/soc/spi@ffda5000";
        a10sr_gpio = "/soc/spi@ffda5000/resource-manager@0/gpio-controller";
        a10sr_rst = "/soc/spi@ffda5000/resource-manager@0/reset-controller";
        sdr = "/soc/sdr@ffcfb100";
        L2 = "/soc/l2-cache@fffff000";
        mmc = "/soc/dwmmc0@ff808000";
        nand = "/soc/nand@ffb90000";
        ocram = "/soc/sram@ffe00000";
        eccmgr = "/soc/eccmgr";
        qspi = "/soc/spi@ff809000";
        rst = "/soc/rstmgr@ffd05000";
        scu = "/soc/snoop-control-unit@ffffc000";
        sysmgr = "/soc/sysmgr@ffd06000";
        timer0 = "/soc/timer0@ffc02700";
        timer1 = "/soc/timer1@ffc02800";
        timer2 = "/soc/timer2@ffd00000";
        timer3 = "/soc/timer3@ffd00100";
        uart0 = "/soc/serial0@ffc02000";
        uart1 = "/soc/serial1@ffc02100";
        usbphy0 = "/soc/usbphy";
        usb0 = "/soc/usb@ffb00000";
        usb1 = "/soc/usb@ffb40000";
        watchdog0 = "/soc/watchdog@ffd00200";
        watchdog1 = "/soc/watchdog@ffd00300";
    };
};
```

The `arria10_hps_bridges` node and its child node `NVDLA_IP_0` is not being shown in /proc/iomem.

Here is the output of cat /proc/iomem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDvhX.png)

Can anyone look into it and let me know why is linux not recognizing the `arria10_hps_bridges` node.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In your kernel config, what is the user/kernel "Memory split" setting set to?

Comment: it was `3G/1G`. Now I have changed it in menuconfig to `2G/2G` and recompiled it. After that, I was able to insert the KMD (which we discussed in the other question) for Ip connected to hps_bridge without error and the device tree node `arria10_hps_bridges` also appeared in `iomem` right after that.  
What I understood from this is that for a node in the device tree to recognized by the kernel, a kernel device driver for the node must running in the kernel. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I also reduced to the size of reserved memory to 500MB since 1G was still large and inserting kmd was resulting in errors

Comment: A node in the device tree exists even if no driver is using it. (But I'm not sure what sort of "recognition" you meant.)

Comment: Actually, the NVDLA_IP node was not listed in the output of `cat /proc/iomem` but after I insert the module NVDLA_IP node got listed in the output of `cat /proc/iomem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. After running the KMD driver for the `NVDLA_IP_0` through the instruction mention in the comments and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063150/warning-aeabi-uldivmod-undefined-symbol-in-opendla-ko) by Ian Abbott, the node appeared in /pro/iomem.